# Impedance magnitude and phase error - Mathematical formula

Tags: impedance, measurement, error, phase, education

Today I read a paper on which there are the terms magnitude error and phase error relative to a comparison between measurements performed with a biosensor and with a benchtop electrochemical impedance spectroscopy (EIS) tool.

[image]

Maybe it means that:

$$magnitude \,\,\, error = \mid \mid Z_{tool} \mid - \mid Z_{biosensor} \mid \mid$$

$$phase \,\,\, error = \mid \angle Z_{tool} - \angle Z_{biosensor} \mid$$

?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this and although your question uses electronic terms it might as well be measurements made by a ruler on a piece of string and you asking what an author might mean by some measurement error. Ask the author. Voting to close.

Comment: Hello @Andyaka, I tried to contact the author many times, he's not answering.

Comment: I know the feeling. I asked [someone](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/111451/gennaro-arguzzi) on [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/239852/rlc-filter-as-amplifier) if they were satisfied with my answer but got no reply.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm so sorry, I forgot to reply to your good answer.

Comment: That's OK, I was trying to inject a little irony and humour but seriously, unless you expect the author of the document in this question walk these EE boards then you are unlikely to get an answer to this question.

Comment: This is a problem. The strange thing is that the paper was published on IEEE and thus it should be understandable for the electronic readers.

Comment: Does the product documentation shed any light on what the errors might be?

Comment: In the paper the author developed a biosensor using op-amp and electrodes. There are not information about the specific error; the only documentation is the op-amp datasheets on which there are other kind of informations.